# how many local repos that git clone creates

Tags: git

From what I understood, when I run `git clone`, then start to add/edit files on my local repo, I have actually 2 repos : `master` and `origin/master` -where the later points to the remote- , I am getting this intuition from what `git fetch` does, It actually gets the latest version from `remote` repo to `origin/master` repo without merging it with local `master`, it is only when I call `git merge` that these remote changes are merged to local `master`

So first question: Am I understanding it correctly? I really have 2 repos on local

Second question: If this is the case, then why pushing a change to the remote server is a 2 step process (`git commit` then `git push`) , If I really have 2 local repos, I believe I will need to make 3 steps : commit to local `master` - merge to `origin/master` then push to `remote/master` ... how now this is only done via 2 steps, is there any implicit action that happens or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: 1) Basically correct, but `origin/master` isn't really a local repo, it's just a pointer to a remote. You cannot push to it without a network connection. `Push` is the equivalent of `pull`, it does `merge` and `push` together (there's no equivalent of `fetch` in pushing).

Comment: @JoshFriedlander .. gr8 ... +10 for the equivalence information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way git models things can be a bit confusing at first, so let's look at some key concepts for this scenario:

- a **repository** is a complete self-contained copy of history; you can pass information between repositories, but there is no "central source of truth" as far as git is concerned
- **commits** are the basic unit you deal with in git; a commit contains a snapshot of the entire repository, pointers to zero or more parent commits (one for a normal commit, two or more for a merge, zero at the very start of the history), and metadata about who committed it, when, etc
- **branches** in git are actually just names pointing to a single commit; from that commit, you can trace history backwards by looking at the parent pointers
- **remotes** are basically just information about where to get extra commits from
- **remote-tracking branches** are read-only branches used to record where those branch names point on a remote server

When you run `git clone`, you get the following:

- a brand new *repository*, entirely self-contained on your computer
- a *remote* called "origin", pointing at the server you cloned from
- some *remote-tracking branches*, recording where, at this point in time, the various branches on the remote server point
- a local copy of every *commit* in the remote server's history, across all branches
- a single local *branch*, which is checked out by default, pointing at the same place as the remote branch with the same name (normally "master" or "main")

You can then unplug your internet, and carry on working, creating as many *commits* and *branches* as you want in your local repository.

When you want to share those commits with other people, you use `git push` to send them to the remote server. This command has two main jobs: to send some *commits* to the remote server; and to tell the remote server to update a *branch* to point to one of those commits. Since it knows that the remote server has been updated, it can update your local read-only "remote-tracking branch" as well.

On the other hand, if you want to have copies of what other people have done on the remote server, you have to use `git fetch` or `git pull`. The purpose of `git fetch` is to ask the server where its branches point, update the local "remote-tracking branches" to match, and then fetch any new *commits* that you don't already have. `git pull` does the same thing, but also updates a *local* branch, either by moving the pointer directly (a "fast-forward merge") or by merging the two histories together.

So to answer more directly:

1. You do not have two repositories; `master` is a local branch, `origin/master` is a remote-tracking branch
2. You don't need to explicitly merge to `origin/master`, because its only purpose is to track where the branch points on the remote server

Answer (score 6):

The thing that you call a repo is a branch in git terminology.
A repo may contain a lot of branches. `master` and `origin/master` are two branches, the `master` represent your local files, while `origin/master` represents a state of `master` in remote repo `origin`. You can have a few remote repos and a few different branches same time. try to read the docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches probably it give you more answers.

Comment: Also have a look at these well made tutorials: [Atlassian Git Tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials)

Comment: thx, the doc is valuable, however I cant find an explicit answer to question 2